# How can I dump my redis database daily?

Tags: redis

I took over a project that is using Redis for temporary storage of objects in a queue. I want to know how I can dump all the objects on a nightly basis. The business only operates from 8am to 8pm and the jobs are completed daily so every day we start fresh.

So my I was wondering how to dump or delete all the data from Redis at midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI - dumping data in the Redis terminology actually means saving it to disk. It appears that what you want is to remove all the data.

There are many ways to do what you want, but basically you need to set up a cron job or similar that executes a [`FLUSHALL`](https://redis.io/commands/flushall) for example. Alternatively, if your Redis server isn't configured with disk persistence, you can simply restart it.